# Creating RDLC report with JSON array

Tags: c#, json, rdlc

I am trying to create `RDLC` report with `JSON` array for my project. This `JSON` array is coming from an API. I have made `RDLC` report using database as `Dataset` directly accesses the `SQL database`, but how to do with API from which a `JSON` array is coming.

I am trying to get `JSON` array on a untyped datatable and then merge it to a typed datatable. Which then should show on `dataset.xsd`, but it is not.

```
public partial class WebForm2 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    [WebMethod]
    [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod()]
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        test();
    }

    public void test()
    {
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        string strJSON = client.DownloadString("Json.txt");
        string chk = strJSON.Replace("\\", "");
        chk = chk.Substring(1, chk.Length - 2);
        DataTable dtUsingMethod = GetJSONToDataTableUsingNewtonSoftDll(chk);
        DataSet1.test_tableDataTable tbl = new DataSet1.test_tableDataTable();
        tbl.Merge(dtUsingMethod);
    }

    public static DataTable GetJSONToDataTableUsingNewtonSoftDll(string JSONData)
    {
        DataTable dt = (DataTable)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(JSONData, (typeof(DataTable)));
        return dt;
    }
}
```

JSON format is given below:

```
"[{\"plant_sl_no\":\"3451\",\"batch_no\":\"3515\",\"batch_no_sl\":\"0\",\"batch_index\":\"6\",\"batch_date\":\"5\/29\/2019 3:00:00 AM\",\"recp_id\":\"M-30(COLUME)\",\"recp_name\":\"M30\",\"pdt_qty\":\"0.50\",\"truck_id\":\"KA 01 C 9771\",\"cust_id\":\"1\",\"load_sent_qty\":\"15.00\",\"site\":\"PHRE HEATER\",\"Prod1_Agg_Name\":\"10MM\",\"Prod1_Agg_Stwt\":\"260.00\",\"Prod1_Agg_Atwt\":\"270.00\",\"Prod1_Agg_Moi\":\"0.00\",\"Prod2_Agg_Name\":\"R SAND\",\"Prod2_Agg_Stwt\":\"395.00\",\"Prod2_Agg_Atwt\":\"410.00\",\"Prod2_Agg_Moi\":\"0.00\",\"Prod3_Agg_Name\":\"20 MM\",\"Prod3_Agg_Stwt\":\"300.00\",\"Prod3_Agg_Atwt\":\"300.00\",\"Prod3_Agg_Moi\":\"0.00\",\"Prod4_Agg_Name\":\"M SAND\",\"Prod4_Agg_Stwt\":\"0.00\",\"Prod4_Agg_Atwt\":\"0.00\",\"Prod4_Agg_Moi\":\"0.00\",\"Prod5_Agg_Name\":\"0\",\"Prod5_Agg_Stwt\":\"0.00\",\"Prod5_Agg_Atwt\":\"0.00\",\"Prod5_Agg_Moi\":\"0.00\",\"Prod6_Agg_Name\":\"-\",\"Prod6_Agg_Stwt\":\"0.00\",\"Prod6_Agg_Atwt\":\"0.00\",\"Prod6_Agg_Moi\":\"0.00\"},{\"plant_sl_no\":\"3451\",\"batch_no\":\"3515\",\"batch_no_sl\":\"0\",\"batch_index\":\"1\",\"batch_date\":\"5\/29\/2019 3:00:00 AM\",\"recp_id\":\"M-30(COLUME)\",\"recp_name\":\"M30\",\"pdt_qty\":\"0.50\",\"truck_id\":\"KA 01 C 9771\",\"cust_id\":\"1\",\"load_sent_qty\":\"15.00\",\"site\":\"PHRE HEATER\",\"Prod1_Agg_Name\":\"10MM\",\"Prod1_Agg_Stwt\":\"260.00\",\"Prod1_Agg_Atwt\":\"260.00\",\"Prod1_Agg_Moi\":\"0.00\",\"Prod2_Agg_Name\":\"R SAND\",\"Prod2_Agg_Stwt\":\"395.00\",\"Prod2_Agg_Atwt\":\"395.00\",\"Prod2_Agg_Moi\":\"0.00\",\"Prod3_Agg_Name\":\"20 MM\",\"Prod3_Agg_Stwt\":\"300.00\",\"Prod3_Agg_Atwt\":\"300.00\",\"Prod3_Agg_Moi\":\"0.00\",\"Prod4_Agg_Name\":\"M SAND\",\"Prod4_Agg_Stwt\":\"0.00\",\"Prod4_Agg_Atwt\":\"0.00\",\"Prod4_Agg_Moi\":\"0.00\",\"Prod5_Agg_Name\":\"0\",\"Prod5_Agg_Stwt\":\"0.00\",\"Prod5_Agg_Atwt\":\"0.00\",\"Prod5_Agg_Moi\":\"0.00\",\"Prod6_Agg_Name\":\"-\",\"Prod6_Agg_Stwt\":\"0.00\",\"Prod6_Agg_Atwt\":\"0.00\",\"Prod6_Agg_Moi\":\"0.00\"},{\"plant_sl_no\":\"3451\",\"batch_no\":\"3515\",\"batch_no_sl\":\"0\",\"batch_index\":\"2\",\"batch_date\":\"5\/29\/2019 3:00:00 AM\",\"recp_id\":\"M-30(COLUME)\",\"recp_name\":\"M30\",\"pdt_qty\":\"0.50\",\"truck_id\":\"KA 01 C 9771\",\"cust_id\":\"1\",\"load_sent_qty\":\"15.00\",\"site\":\"PHRE HEATER\",\"Prod1_Agg_Name\":\"10MM\",\"Prod1_Agg_Stwt\":\"260.00\",\"Prod1_Agg_Atwt\":\"260.00\",\"Prod1_Agg_Moi\":\"0.00\",\"Prod2_Agg_Name\":\"R SAND\",\"Prod2_Agg_Stwt\":\"395.00\",\"Prod2_Agg_Atwt\":\"395.00\",\"Prod2_Agg_Moi\":\"0.00\",\"Prod3_Agg_Name\":\"20 MM\",\"Prod3_Agg_Stwt\":\"300.00\",\"Prod3_Agg_Atwt\":\"300.00\",\"Prod3_Agg_Moi\":\"0.00\",\"Prod4_Agg_Name\":\"M SAND\",\"Prod4_Agg_Stwt\":\"0.00\",\"Prod4_Agg_Atwt\":\"0.00\",\"Prod4_Agg_Moi\":\"0.00\",\"Prod5_Agg_Name\":\"0\",\"Prod5_Agg_Stwt\":\"0.00\",\"Prod5_Agg_Atwt\":\"0.00\",\"Prod5_Agg_Moi\":\"0.00\",\"Prod6_Agg_Name\":\"-\",\"Prod6_Agg_Stwt\":\"0.00\",\"Prod6_Agg_Atwt\":\"0.00\",\"Prod6_Agg_Moi\":\"0.00\"}]"
```

Expected result is I want to generate report using JSON array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found an answer which is working for me. I am posting it here hopefully it would be helpful for others also.
The problem here is we need datasource for the RDLC report. Since we cannot use Sql database we have to make our own custom datasource.

Step 1. add a class file.

Step 2. Code within class file:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Converters;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters;
using System.IO;
using System.Data;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Net;

namespace Batch_report
{
    public class batch_data 
    {
        public string plant_sl_no { get; set; }
        public string batch_no { get; set; }
        public string batch_no_sl { get; set; }
        public string batch_index { get; set; }
        public string batch_date { get; set; }
        public string recp_id { get; set; }
        public string recp_name { get; set; }
        public string pdt_qty { get; set; }
        public string truck_id { get; set; }
        public string cust_id { get; set; }
        public string load_sent_qty { get; set; }
        public string site { get; set; }
    }
    public class Custom_batch
    {
        [WebMethod]
        [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod()]
        public static List<batch_data> GetEmployeeName()
        {
            //List<string> abc = new List<string>();
            //string[] arr;
            WebClient client = new WebClient();
            string info = client.DownloadString("http://json.txt");
            string chk = info.Replace("\\", "");
            chk = chk.Substring(1, chk.Length - 2);

            List<batch_data> obj = new List<batch_data>();
            obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<batch_data>>(chk);

            return obj;
        }
    }
}
```

Step 3. Build your class file, and you will get a batch_report.dll file. Add this .dll to the reference folder of your project.

Step 4. Add report or report wizard from the toolbox. When you add a window will open asking for dataset. name your dataset, then in datasource select batch_report from the dropdown list.In "Available Datasets"select the method from which you are getting data which in my case is from Custom_batch class and method is - GetEmployeeName().

Step 5. click Next until it is done and after that yo can design your report as well.